# Does this Functor combinator have a name?

Tags: haskell, functor

I have a combinator `C` and a `Functor` `instance` defined as follows:

```
data C f1 f2 a = C (f1 a) (f2 a)

instance
  ( Functor f1
  , Functor f2
  )
    => Functor (C f1 f2)
  where
    fmap g (C a b) = C (fmap g a) (fmap g b)
```

In plain English I might describe `C` as a product type in which the `fmap` instance distributes.

My implementation here is fine for my purposes here, but I want to know if there is a proper name for this combinator in the haskell or category-theoretic jargon, so that I might project to future users of this library what this does, or even use existing code instead if such exists.

Does this combinator already have a name?

Comment: Yes, it's [Product](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html)

Comment: This site has the whole enchilada of functor combinators: https://blog.jle.im/entry/functor-combinatorpedia.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [functor product](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Product.html#Product), defined in the `Data.Functor.Product` module from the `base` library.  From the link:

```
data Product f g a = Pair (f a) (g a)

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Product f g) where
    fmap f (Pair x y) = Pair (fmap f x) (fmap f y)
```

(To be precise, both are just a products of higher-kinded types, not necessarily functors, but `C f g` and `Product f g` are only functors if `f` and `g` are both functors as well.)